# Not calling function when using PageMethods

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a server-side function using a client-side function.
Everywhere I looked I saw people using AJAX, and it seemed simple enough. But when I try calling the method all it does is reload the page.

.aspx code:

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

<button id="test" onClick="ButtonClick(this.id)">test</button>

<script>
function ButtonClick(id) {
    PageMethods.ButtonClickMethod(id);
}
</script>
```

.cs code:

```cs
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   [WebMethod]
   public static void ButtonClickMethod(string id)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id = " +id);
   }
}
```

I get no output in the console.

I tried to look at a couple of sources but they all look identical to what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we are confusing two things here.

You can adopt "page" methods, and they are somewhat easier to use then a striangt "ajax" call in JavaScript.

So, lets call your new page method both ways (but, they are not related to the button click) you have. Or perhaps better said, if you want a button click to fire/launch/use/run the page method, then the button will have/need/use/require a button click in the client side JavaScript code.

So, first up (and I'm only do this example first), since I never did get around to using page methods.

So, first up, a your page methods are not some button click, but in fact a code stub in the code behind.

Some things to keep in mind:

While these page methods are rather cool, since then you do NOT have a full browser post-back and full so called "round trip", they have a rather LARGE downside.

That big downside is since the web page "remains" on the client side browser (and desktop), then such code behind does NOT have use of controls on the web page. That means if the code behind needs to operate on values, you have to pass the values to the web method.

And if you going to update a control on the web page, then once again, the client side code has to do that update of the control.

So, lets say we want to convert Fahrenheit to Celusis.

So, we drop in a text box to enter the temperature. Another text box below for the converted result, and then of course a plain jane button to run our code.

So, we have this markup:

```
        <h3>Tempature Converter</h3>
        <div style="width:20%;text-align:right">
        Enter Fahrenheit: <asp:TextBox ID="txtF" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Result as C:<asp:TextBox ID="txtC" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Convert" CssClass="btn"
                OnClientClick="myconvert();return false"
                />
        </div>
        
        <script>

            function myconvert() {

                var F = $('#txtF').val()
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "FtoC.aspx/FarToCel",
                    data: JSON.stringify({Fvalue : F}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (returnstuff) {
                        $('#txtC').val(returnstuff.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

Note how we dropped in a plain jane asp.net button. But, we use a client side click event (and return false, so no post-back of the page).

I also assume (used) jQuery, as it quit a bit easier to make such a ajax call.

the code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static  double FarToCel(double Fvalue)
    {
        double C = (Fvalue - 32) / 1.8;
        return C;
    }
```

And thus the result is this:

[image]

So, the whole idea (whole goal here) is we thus do NOT suffer nor have a whole page post-back. So, you not see any browser "spin" or a page post back + round trip.

Now, we can of course use "page methods" to do the same thing.

So, lets drop another button below the above, and use a page method.

First up, we have to drop in a script manager.

So, right at top (just after form tag), then this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">

    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And now lets drop below the first button, our 2nd button our button code looks like this:

```
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Convert (page method example)" CssClass="btn"
                OnClientClick="myconvert2();return false"
                />
```

And the client side js function is now this:

```
            function myconvert2() {
                var F = $('#txtF').val()
                PageMethods.FarToCel(F,allgood)
            }

            function allgood(myresponse, userContext, methodName) {
                $('#txtC').val(myresponse)
            }
```

So, the 2nd approach is certainly less wiring up. and of course we could SKIP using jQuery (or maybe we don't have it), and use pure js code. So, the page methods is certainly somewhat easier, since we really don't even need jQuery code at all.

In pure js code (no jQuery shortcuts), then our 2nd example becomes this:

```
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Convert (page method example)" CssClass="btn"
                OnClientClick="myconvert2();return false"
                />

       <script>

            function myconvert2() {
                var F = document.getElementById("txtF").value
                PageMethods.FarToCel(F,allgood)
            }

            function allgood(myresponse, userContext, methodName) {
                tBoxC = document.getElementById("txtC")
                tBoxC.value = myresponse
            }

   </script>
```

And thus again, then this:

[image]

so, without question, if you don't have/use jQuery, then page methods are quite a bit easier to use.

And to be fair, EVEN with jQuery, page methods are still less effort.

So, page methods STILL require you to call some js function in the client code,  and in some cases, this does not necessary have to be the result of a button click, but in most cases I suppose it would be.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, however i still dont understand why its not working for me because as far as i can tell im doing it like your examples. does it have to be `<asp:button>` for it to work?

Comment: button don't matter - you could put a alert('start') in your js code (or a console.log('start') in the js code to be sure that the js code is actually being called. However, to answer your question, no, a asp.net button is not required, but you MOST certainly don't want a post back to occur, else that will of course mess up the whole page. So, I used a plain jane asp.net button, but the return false is VERY important, since I don't want a post-back, and in fact if the button does post-back, then this will not work. But, plain jane HTML button, or whatever to call the js code should be fine.